# Handle Unavailable Layer screen appears when using GeoJson files in QGIS project

Tags: qgis-3, geojson

When I open a project with GeoJson layers in QGIS 3, the "Handle Unavailable Layers" screen always opens. After using the "Auto-Find" button, the files were found without any problems. This is why I do not think that there is a problem with the path.

Is this a timeout problem because the GeoJson files are too big or something?